# Using darch to predict new sample class

Tags: r, deep-learning, predict

I am trying to use the darch package to create a dbn of several stacked RBMs. I'm new to the deep learning scene so my question is: what is the equivalent of the predict function in the glmnet/randomForest/knn...etc packages?

After training the dbn, how do I predict on an outside sample? for example (this is the example provided in the package)

```
## Not run:
# Generating the datasets
inputs <- matrix(c(0,0,0,1,1,0,1,1),ncol=2,byrow=TRUE)
outputs <- matrix(c(0,1,1,0),nrow=4)
# Generating the darch
darch <- newDArch(c(2,4,1),batchSize=2)
# Pre-Train the darch
darch <- preTrainDArch(darch,inputs,maxEpoch=1000)
# Prepare the layers for backpropagation training for
# backpropagation training the layer functions must be
# set to the unit functions which calculates the also
# derivatives of the function result.
layers <- getLayers(darch)
for(i in length(layers):1){
layers[[i]][[2]] <- sigmoidUnitDerivative
}
setLayers(darch) <- layers
rm(layers)
# Setting and running the Fine-Tune function
setFineTuneFunction(darch) <- backpropagation
darch <- fineTuneDArch(darch,inputs,outputs,maxEpoch=1000)
# Running the darch
darch <- darch <- getExecuteFunction(darch)(darch,inputs)
outputs <- getExecOutputs(darch)
cat(outputs[[length(outputs)]])
```

Suppose now we have

```
inputsTest <- matrix(c(0,1,0,0,0,0,1,1),ncol=2,byrow=TRUE)
```

How do I get the output?

also, can someone explain what this line does:

```
darch <- darch <- getExecuteFunction(darch)(darch,inputs)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, this has been really helpful, there is a straight up predict command. 
https://github.com/maddin79/darch

Answer (score 0):

Darch has a bunch of getters and setters to the fields you could access by your own. Execute function is one of them.

For me, the easiest way is just do darch `<- darch@executeFunction(darch, inputs)`

Outputs of all layers will be in darch@executeOutput